# Why can't Mavericks get the "process descriptor"?

Tags: macos, process, osx-mavericks, osx-mountain-lion, descriptor

I have an app that when clicking on a log line in it's debug log console opens MonoDevelop.
This used to work in Mountain Lion but in Mavericks It doesn't work and give this error:

Failed to open file: unable to get process descriptor for /Applications/Unity/MonoDevelop.app

What has changed in Mavericks that would cause this error?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Are you developing an app using the MonoDevelop? (Thus a MonoDevelop question)? Or are you just using an app that does?   If there's some more detail on the development side, somebody might be able to help, however with this level of detail, it is unlikely.   You might also want to look in the Console.app and see if there are any other error messages that might be informative.

Comment: I am using Unity whose default editor is MonoDevelop. And ever since upgrading to Mavericks Unity is giving those errors when it tries to open MonoDevelop: EditorHelper: Attempting to open file (using Apple events): /Volumes/Data/Library/Unity/bug reports/test/test.sln.
EditorHelper: Failed to open file: unable to get process descriptor for /Applications/Unity 4.5/MonoDevelop.app.